# I only get second part of string parsing XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

i have an app that parse an XML i added to my application bundle, it con taint child nodes with string, sometimes it long enough, so i can't get it in output as full (i only get "last" part of string). This his how i tried to fix problem:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{


    if (isDescription) [self._currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"description"];


    if (isDescription) {
        if (self._currentPosition[@"description"])
        {
            NSMutableString *str = self._currentPosition[@"description"];

            [str appendString:self.descriptionString];

        }
        else
        {
            [self._currentPosition setValue:[NSMutableString stringWithString:self.descriptionString] forKey:@"description"];
        }
    };

}
```

self.description string is a string i declared in .h file to make it mutable, but still, i got an error SIGABRT - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'`

Is there another way to fix that? I had same problem in other app, but previous code fix that just fine, but now i parse an XML i add to application bundle, and in another case that was just a web source.

So my question is - how to make "complete" string to fully output it?

There is a bit more information  for you that might be useful - a console output of my string:

```
2014-02-16 16:01:51.500 superApp[294:60b] Ло́бное ме́сто — памятник древнерусской архитектуры, находящийся в Москве, на Красной площади. Представляет собой возвышение, окружённое каменной оградой.
2014-02-16 16:01:51.527 superApp[294:60b] лощади.
```

In text output in only get - "лощади."

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: log these two self.descriptionString & self._currentPosition[@"description"]. you have values in it for  this 'if (self._currentPosition[@"description"])' condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
NSMutableString *str = self._currentPosition[@"description"];
```

Should be

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self._currentPosition[@"description"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably self._currentPosition[@"description"] is NSString, not NSMutableString.
You should change this

```
NSMutableString *str = self._currentPosition[@"description"];
```

to this

```
NSMutableString *str = [[self._currentPosition[@"description"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Avt everything is fine now!